# Size of $p$-subgroups of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, where $p$ divides the order of $G$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a nontrivial finite group. In his book "Finite Group Theory", M. Isaacs proves the following two results:

> **Corollary 3.3**: Let $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Then, $o(\sigma) < |G|$.

> **Corollary 3.4**: Let $P$ be an abelian $p$-subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and suppose $p \nmid |G|$ . Then, $|P| < |G|$.

---

This lead me to the following question:

> **Question**: is the same result (**3.4**) true when $p \mid |G|$?

I'm guessing "no", but I know very few concrete examples of automorphism groups of finite groups. If $G$ is cyclic, for instance, $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)| = \phi(n) < n$, meaning the question is automatically true.

If $G$ is dihedral, I found $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \simeq C_n \rtimes C_n^\times$, where $|G| = 2n$ and the action is $x^p \cdot x^q = x^{pq}, x^p \in C_n^\times, x^q \in C_n$, which has order $n \phi(n)$; in particular, for cases like $n = 8$, it seems like I could find a counter-example, but I'm still struggling a bit to find *abelian* subgroups of this semidirect product, since I'm a bit new to these groups...

EDIT: As has been suggested in the comments, the second question has been moved to [another post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741891/abelian-subgroups-of-the-group-of-automorphisms-of-a-finite-group)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, I just clumped them together because they referenced the same theorems and were very closely related. I’ll create a second post with the second question and link it to this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer Question 1: the answer is no.

The automorphism group of an elementary abelian group of order $p^{2n}$ is isomorphic to the group ${\rm GL}(2n,p)$, which has an elementary abelian subgroup of order $p^{n^2/4}$ consisting of upper unitriangular matrices with nonzero entries above the main diagonal only in the upper right $n \times n$ block.

In other words, matrices
$(\alpha_{ij})$ with $\alpha_{ii}=1$ for all $i$, and $\alpha_{ij}=0$ for $i \ne j$ except when $i<n$ and $j>n$.