# Exercise 5.26 from Isaacs Character Theory of Finite Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $X \subset G \setminus \{1\}$, with $n = |X|$. What I want to prove is the following:

> Suppose that, for every prime $p < n$, the $p$-Sylow subgroups are cyclic. Then, there exists $\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ such that $X \cap \ker\chi = \emptyset$.

I was struggling with the abelian case and took a look at the original paper ("A characterization of groups in terms of the degrees of their characters") and understood the proof. However, in the book, Isaacs gives the following hint for the abelian case:

> *Hint:* Let $N$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ with respect to the property $N \cap X = \emptyset$. Then show $G/N$ is cyclic.

Trying to prove this hint, I got nowhere. Contrary to the proof in the paper (which used induction), I have no control over the structure of the $N$ that appears here, since it isn't constructed from the ground-up.

My idea would be to show that every Sylow subgroup of the quotient $G/N$ is cyclic, but, since I don't even know the order of $N$, I don't know how to relate the Sylow subgroups in the quotient to those of the original group (they're the quotients of things of the form $PN$, but that's pretty much all I know).

Assuming $G = \langle X \rangle$ (WLOG), the quotient is generated by the projections of the $n$ elements $x_i \in X$, so another way to approach this would be to directly show that $x_1^\alpha x_j^{-\beta} \in N$ for some powers $\alpha, \beta$, but, again, I'm at a loss...

Do you have any hints as for how to prove the hint and get the result this way?

Thanks in advance!

PS: This isn't homework; I've taken it upon myself to solve all exercises in the first few chapters of the book and have no-one to ask for help...

Edit: clarified the request

Comment: Hint: if $G/N$ is cyclic, then there is a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ whose kernel is exactly $N$.

Comment: @Aphelli How does this help me prove that $G/N$ is cyclic?

Comment: I thought you were trying to prove that there existed $\chi \in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$ such that […] assuming Isaacs’ hint?

Comment: @Aphelli My problem is the opposite, actually: I don’t know how to prove the hint… maybe I didn’t express myself well, sorry - I’ve edited the post to make this more clear!

Comment: Ah, I see. Then here’s another hint: show that for $q \geq n$ prime, given any two elements of $G/N$ with order $q$, one of them is a multiple of the other.

Comment: @Aphelli Assuming your hint, I can see why a $q$-Sylow would be cyclic in the quotient. That said, I'm not sure how to prove the hint. Any subgroup of order $q$ in $G/N$ corresponds to a subgroup of order $q |N|$ of $G$. Then, by the maximality of $N$, it contains some element of $X$. This is where I get stuck - I've tried this kind of argument before, but I can't see why containing an element of $X$ would help...

Comment: If the Sylow $q$-subgroup was not cyclic then it would have at least $q+1$ subgroups of order $q$, each of which would contain an element of $X$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you so much! That did the trick!

Comment: off-topic: @Gauss, have you seen my answer to your older question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741891/abelian-subgroups-of-the-group-of-automorphisms-of-a-finite-group/4823171 ?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki I have, though I haven’t taken the time to properly read it yet. I’ll let you know over there when I do! Thank you for the answer, by the way!