Dimension of the center of a block
Let $G$ be a finite group and let $F$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. I've been studying some modular character theory from Navarro's "Characters and blocks of finite groups" and came across the following question:

Let $B$ be a block of a finite group $G$. Then, show that the number of ordinary irreducible characters belonging to $B$ is the dimension of $Z(B)$ over $F$.

Just for some context, we can decompose the algebra $FG$ as $$FG = \bigoplus_{B \in \operatorname{Bl}(G)} B$$ where the blocks $B$ are indecomposable ideals of $FG$. Each of them is an algebra with unity $e_B$, where this is a primitive central idempotent associated to the decomposition. Then, a module $M$ belongs to $B$ if the idempotent acts as a unity in $M$; otherwise, $e_B M = 0$.
If $p \nmid |G|$, then these blocks are just the matrix algebras given in the Wedderburn-Artin decomposition of $FG$, and each of them is associated to a unique and distinct irreducible representation of $G$. Also, the center of each is one-dimensional, meaning the problem is true in this case. This is actually how we get that the dimension of the center of $Z(FG)$ as an $F$-vector space is the number of distinct irreducible representations of $G$ up to equivalence.
However, if $p \mid |G|$, the argument above doesn't work anymore, as $FG$ is no longer semi-simple. In that case, I don't know how to analyze $\dim_FZ(B)$... I tried to use the standard basis of $Z(FG)$, which are the class sums of $G$, but couldn't get a basis for $Z(B)$ from that...
Does anyone have a hint as for how to solve the question above?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: fixed a small mistake. Also, just to clarify, I put some definitions and the like in the question, but feel free to use more than that!

I can probably answer this, but not today. It would be nice if you can check my answer to your older question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741891/abelian-subgroups-of-the-group-of-automorphisms-of-a-finite-group

@BrauerSuzuki If you could help, I would greatly appreciate it! Also, you are right - I forgot to go back and take a proper look at it. I’ve now corrected that mistake and accepted your answer!

To clarify (for those who may not be familiar with the terminology): irreducible characters here refers to complex irreducible characters, and not to irreducible representations over the given algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. So the assertion is that the number of ordinary characters belonging to a given block is the dimension of the center of that block.

@Stephen Forgot to specify - it is fixed now!

I think the proof can be done similarly as in Theorem 2.6 of Navarro's book, which you are citing. More precisely, the block idempotent $f_B$ decomposes over $\mathbb{C}$ into $f_B=\sum_{\chi\in\mathrm{Irr}(B)}e_\chi$. The problem is that the $e_\chi$ do not live in $\mathbf{R}G$ (where as in the book, $\mathbf{R}$ is the ring of algebraic integers).
We may write $e_\chi=\sum_{g\in G}\alpha_gg$ with $\alpha_g\in\mathbf{K}$ (algebraic numbers). By Lemma 2.5 of the book, there exists some $\beta_\chi$ such that $\alpha_g\beta_\chi\in\mathbf{R}$ for all $g\in G$, but not all of these numbers become zero in $F$.
Let $t_\chi:=(\beta e_\chi)^*=(\beta e_\chi)^*e_B\in Z(B)$. Suppose that the $t_\chi$ are linearly dependent, say $s:=\sum_{\chi\in\mathrm{Irr}(B)}\gamma_\chi t_\chi=0$. Since the $e_\chi$ are orthogonal idempotents, we get the contradiction $\gamma_\chi\beta_\chi t_\chi=t_\chi s=0$. Hence, the $t_\chi$ are linearly independent and $\dim Z(B)\ge k(B)$. On the other hand, $\sum_B\dim Z(B)=\dim Z(FG)=k(G)=\sum_Bk(B)$. This shows $\dim Z(B)=k(B)$.
I hope this makes sense.

When you put the bar over $\beta e_\chi$, you mean the projection onto $F$, right? Just making sure

Yes, good point. I have changed it to $.^*$ like in the book.
